# Can I get the list a slice is part of?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to get the original list from a slice in Python 3 for debugging purposes, something like

```
L = [1,2,3,4,5]
S = L[2:3]
X = S.originalList()
# X == L
```

Is that even possible in python?

Comment: No, it's not possible. Slicing makes a *copy* of the list, and doesn't retain any connection to the original.

Comment: Are slices like hard copies? Because if not, there might be some associativity somewhere.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis what do you mean *"hard"* copies? They're *shallow* copies.

Comment: I mean the opposite of shallow copies. A copy which does not get affected when the original object gets editted.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis ah, they're usually called *deep* copies in Python. No, slices are shallow; they contain references to the items in the original list, but not to the original list itself. Deep copies contain references to neither.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Cool man, thanks!

Comment: To clear that up: In the example code, `S` is a new list, populated with the same items as `L[2:3]`. If you do `S[0] = 'foo'`, it won't change any of the elements in `L`, but if `L` was containing objects, then the items in `S` would point to the same objects.

Comment: aha, actualy new independent list, objects are copied by reference but primitive types are actually hard-copies?
If that's right, could you make an answer out of it?

Comment: @Martin no, all objects are treated the same, since assignment only every creates references in Python. [This article](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html) explains it well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it's not possible with the standard python `list` because slicing creates a new list. The items referenced in the list point to the same objects (it's a shallow copy) but that doesn't help because the python list is just a wrapper (with lots of extras) for a list of pointers.

This has the effect that you can change the list elements of one list without modifying the other which makes it extremly complicated to assess what cases your `.originallist` property or method should check.

```
>>> list1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
>>> list2 = list1[2:5]

>>> list2[1] = 10

>>> list1, list2
([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [3, 10, 5])
```

However there is already a data-structure that uses memory-views instead of shallow copies when sliced: `numpy.ndarray` and it's attribute [`numpy.ndarray.base`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.base.html#numpy-ndarray-base).

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> arr1 = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])
>>> arr2 = arr1[2:5]

>>> arr2.base is arr1  # it's called "base" instead of "originallist".
True
```

Note that with numpy arrays any changes to `arr2` are propagated to `arr1`! Depending on your use-case numpy.arrays might be overkill and a simple subclass or wrapper around a list could be enough.

Answer (score 0):

You could create an extension class for lists in which you need this kind of functionality. So first you'll need a list to which you can add attributes (via http://code.activestate.com/recipes/579103-python-addset-attributes-to-list/):

```
class L(list):
    def __new__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(L, self).__new__(self, args, kwargs)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if len(args) == 1 and hasattr(args[0], '__iter__'):
            list.__init__(self, args[0])
        else:
            list.__init__(self, args)
        self.__dict__.update(kwargs)

    def __call__(self, **kwargs):
        self.__dict__.update(kwargs)
        return self
```

Now you can add to this class another method:

```
    def slice(self, left, right):
        S = L(self[left:right])
        S.originalList = self
        return S
```

And now you can do:

```
l = L(1,2,3,4,5)
S = l.slice(2,3)
try:
    X = S.originalList
except AttributeError:
    pass # here you can handle the case where S doesn't have an original list
# X == L
```